# Redirect specific host to subdirectory without affecting different hosts with .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-routing

Is it possible to redirect a specific host to a different subdirectory without affecting the other hosts that are on the same virtual domain?
For example:

```
www.example1.com -> www.example1.com/index.html
www.example2.com -> www.example2.com/test.html
```

where both domains are running on the same virtual host and thus share the same .htaccess file and all other files and directories.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the `.htaccess` you can use the `%{HTTP_HOST}` to check for the URL the person is requesting. So for example:

```
# http://www.example1.com => http://www.example1.com/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html

# http://www.example2.com => http://www.example2.com/test.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.html
```

---

You can view these rules in action [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=5034a07f-6627-57ea-bf77-587f35d2e734).

---

Edit:
Via comments, to preven looping, you could ensure we are not requesting test.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example2.be [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.html [R,L]
```

Comment: This gives me a redirect loop, I think he keeps on expanding the www.example2.com
My .htaccess file is: 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example2.be [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.html [R,L]

Comment: I added a condition to my answer above. Now the request won't redirect when trying to hit `test.html`